# Fast file directory level change in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a thumb drive. I like this thumb drive because it has three boot images on it.

To change what's booting, all I have to do is move the files from the appropriate folder up to the main level. Windows sees me do this and rewrites the tree. Super quick.

I tried to automate this with a batch file. The robocopy move command was trivial to write but painful to watch, because it actually wrote the new (**huge**) files first. I was shocked and appalled at my own lack of foresight while I allowed it to finish.

The question: is there an elegant way to get windows to do this one-level move?

I'd like to put a batch file in the storage folder where the rest of the boot files reside, if at all practical.

Comment: This is as simple as using the [`move`](https://www.computerhope.com/movehlp.htm) command. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The move command has to be scripted  to recurse subdirectories, as move has no recurse option. I'm not above using it, but I didn't want to.

Comment: I’m not sure that is accurate. When you move a folder it moves the entire contents of that folder. It doesn’t care how many files or folders are under it because it simply relinks it in the file table.

Comment: You can always use the much more powerful powershell `move-item` if `move` doesn’t work. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-6

Comment: `move <directory> <newDirectory>`

Comment: Move * will only grab the files without a for loop to specify the directories. Unless it's my turn to have missed something.

Comment: Right, okay, let me try to explain my whine clearly. I can move all the files up one level trivially. I can move one directory at a time trivially. I cannot tell move to take all of the directories in the current directory and kick them up one level.

Comment: Ok. I’m misunderstanding that you are trying to move only files and not an entire folder. In that case powershell’s `move-item` may be the best option. Or a recursive batch file is needed. That’s not really that hard to make.

Comment: I figured this was how I was going to end up. I spend all day coding Perl making tools - I was just really hoping someone had something new to add to the whole "move doesn't recurse on it's own" thing. I have to write one of these for each flavor of my startup tool and frankly I'm lazy.

Comment: Can you update your question with the `ROBOCOPY` code you used.

Comment: @squashman, if you want that to try and help me, thank you. But this was a little side project, and I was hoping for a better method of recursive subdirectory level changes, which is a known fiddly bit with the windows move command. If you just want it for yourself, I'll happily post it, but I have since resorted to writing all of the looping batch files i needed to do this job.

Comment: @SeanBoddy, just wanted to see if you were using the command correctly.

Comment: @Squashman, indeed, thank you. Robocopy is really intended more for moving much larger things much farther away, and it doesn't try to collapse this sort of thing into a level change. Even with the \move or \mov switches, the files are copied in totality before the original gets deleted. The boot packages I'm using contain whole operating systems and none are smaller than 2 gigabytes, making this copy non-trivial.